# ERROR: NotImplementedError: this is an abstract class in speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am new to coding and I started to learn how to code Python a few weeks ago. I've been testing with speech_recognition, and I always encounter this error that has been bugging me for a few days. I'm using Python 3.9.5 on Windows.

```
import speech_recognition

ai_ear = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.Recognizer() as mic:
    print("AI: I'm listening...")
    audio = ai_ear.listen(mic)

try:
    you = ai_ear.recognize_google(audio)
except:
    you = ""

you = ai_ear.recognize_google(audio)

print(you)
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Python Projects\3-AI.py", line 4, in <module>
    with speech_recognition.Recognizer() as mic:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 51, in __enter__
    raise NotImplementedError("this is an abstract class")
NotImplementedError: this is an abstract class
```

P.S: In advance, can you also tell me what does "abstract class" mean?

Comment: btw, No, you should look up what *abstract class* means first. Then you will be in a position to ask questions about it.

Comment: Did you mean: `with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:`?

Comment: I did search for abstract class meaning, but I was too dumb to understand it. Was hoping for a more thorough explanation of the phrase though...

Comment: But on this forum you can only ask one question at a time, otherwise the pages are just too confusing. Which question did you want to ask?

Comment: I want to fix the error first, then I can focus on the error itself. I did try to fix the error in multiple ways before, but none of them worked.

Comment: So, Did you mean: ‘with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:’?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but I think it's 'speech_recognition.Recognizer() as mic:'

Comment: Well, I know that *you* think, but I'm asking have you tried my suggestion? Does it run without the error? Does it do anything for you?

Comment: Sorry, I did try your suggestion though, but it gets another error: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Python Projects\3-AI.py", line 6, in <module>
    audio = ai_ear.listen(mic)
AttributeError: 'Microphone' object has no attribute 'listen'

Comment: So, how did you generate ai_ear?

Comment: "ai_ear" is just a name, like "r" in r = speech_recognition.Microphone()

Comment: So, have you looked at the documentation? It’s pretty clear what you should do.

Comment: I'm not sure what is documentation you're talking about, sorry.

Comment: Err... Well that's what google is for. Try [here](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition) first and then [here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/tree/master/examples) on github.

Comment: Thanks! I'll read them.

Comment: Umm... It's not working (for me). I've read the document multiples times already, but still cannot find a proper answer for this error.

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class means that the class has to be inherited. The abstract methods don't do anything by themselves.